# How to Install telnet through a file?

Tags: centos, yum, telnet

I need to install telnet in a remote server (Centos 7), but when I use `yum install`, the process is stuck in finding mirrors (probably because the server lacks accessibility).

I had the same problem installing java and I externally copied the `jdk.rpm` file and did a `yum localinstall` to install it.

Is there a similar way to install telnet?

Comment: Why would you want to install telnet on a server that you can already SSH to?  In any case, you should already know the answer - copy the telnet RPM package onto the server and install it?

Comment: Focus in understanding things and using your head and not following blindly recipes, so you might learn and get more experienced. From the text, you have already done the same in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the Telnet RPM [from here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/telnet-0.17-64.el7.x86_64.rpm), transfer it to your server, and install it in the same way:

```
yum install /path/to/telnet-0.17-64.el7.x86_64.rpm
```